# Expose "all changes since" via wordpress JSON api

Tags: mysql, wordpress, realm, wordpress-json-api

I'm struggling to find a solution to what I thought would be a common requirement so I'm hoping someone can help me with some pointers on what to search for/areas to explore.

**Background**

I'm building an iOS mobile app. I'm storing data locally using realm.io. The app is preinstalled with a snapshot of the content of a Wordpress mySQL database (it uses custom types). The content of the WP database is only written via the Wordpress install, the mobile app cannot write data.

**Objective**

So, I want to be able to check for changes since a given date (whenever the local database was last updated) and send the changed records to the mobile app (via the wp JSON api?).

I think I can fetch "posts since a date" but I need a full list of all create, update and delete operations since a given date.

Since the app is read-only I thought this type of one-way sync would be pretty straight forward but I can't find a common solution.

Any ideas to point me in the right direction would be great. Obviously, if anyone has any experience of doing this sort if thing with realm.io then that would be amazing :-)

Answer (score 1):

<del>Realm doesn't support yet any sort of synchronization mechanism across different files. We have an [issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/913) about that though, but you're likely searching rather for a solution in the **immediate** future.</del>

**Update:** Realm launched the [Realm Mobile Platform](https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-platform/). This offers synchronization functionalities and would greatly simplify the solution for this use case.

You could use e.g. the server-side Node.js binding to pull new data from your MySQL Wordpress installation and push them to a global Realm served by the Realm Object Server. This can be read-only synchronized from the mobile apps, which would automatically receive the deltas and provide updated data to your users.

---

Whatever mechanism you come up yourself though in the meantime, it would require that you have read-write access from your iOS application to the realm database, so that you can update it with new data.

Pushing changed records as you describe is likely not going to work.

Apple's Push Notification service (APNS), which is the only back communication channel that works when your app is in the background or suspended, allows you to send very small payloads. You would use that to signalize your iOS app, that something changed on the server-side and there is new data to load. You would then initiate a request to a JSON-based API, wait for the response, map the returned JSON to Realm objects and store them in your database.
You want probably read more in the ["Downloading Content in the Background"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW5) section of background execution chapter in the official App Programming Guides for iOS.

While pre-seeding the database from the app bundle seems like a nice idea, because the user wouldn't need to wait initially after downloading the app, that will enlarge the app itself with data, which might become in the future completely irrelevant.

Comment: thanks for your comments. I've not been clear; the ios app **will** be writing to the local realm db but won't be sending any updates back to the 'master' database on the server.

The scenario is something like this: 1000 records in realm pre-loaded with the app, 'mirroring' a master mySQL db on the server. After a week, the app is opened and 4 records have been added, 3 records have been changed and 1 deleted from the master db. I only want to expose details of these 8 records rather than re-send a new snapshot of all 999 records to the app.

Comment: I had seen that issue/thread about syncing and then spent some time looking at Firebase which has great support for real-time syncing. However, because I only need one-way syncing I think the benefits of Realm outweigh the negatives of having to roll my own sync logic. I'm now looking at Dreamfactory which seems like it might do what I need. I'll post an update if it does :-) Thanks.

Comment: **Update**: We introduced the Realm Mobile Platform, which brings synchronization to your Realms. I updated the answer accordingly as I think it greatly simplifies this use-case.